# CSS width in percents is shorter for select than other tags

Tags: css, width

I noticed that while applying `width: 90%` to several elements, the `select` gets rendered shorter, than the other elements.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6zDg/2/) shows that behavior.

I checked with Opera, IE9, Safari, Firefox and Chrome. All showing the same behavior. So it seems to be rather some strange specification than a bug.

Can someone elaborate on my observations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every browser may apply some specific (and different) style settings to its UI elements: to get rid of browser specific style just try to set the `box-sizing` property, e.g.

```
.width {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Further information on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing)